# WebService (CF 3.5) and Class Inheritance?

Tags: web-services, compact-framework

I use a simple WebService returning a Test Class as Response. The Test Class has a Base Class containing an int and a string field. The Server sets these two fields of the Base Class.

If i use the WebService on a PC (.Net Console Application) eveything works fine (the int and string field of the Base Class are filled) - but under CF 3.5 the fields of the Base Class are always null.

Does there is a limitation using WebService + Class Inheritance on CF ?