# .NET Compact Framework 3.5 Serialization Problem with Derived Classes

Tags: .net, compact-framework, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I try to serialize with XmlSerializer - but i have problems with Derived class:

These are my classes:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(Child))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.demo.com")]
public class BaseClass {
  private int myIntField;
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
  public int myInt {
    get { return this.myIntField; }
    set { this.myIntField = value; }
  }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.demo.com")]
public class Child : BaseClass {
  private int keyField;
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
  public int key {
    get { return this.keyField; }
    set { this.keyField = value; }
  }
}
```

found out, that serialization for the parent field only works, if there is included the namespace:

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Child));

// NOT WORKING
StringReader sr = new StringReader(
  "<Child>" +
   "<myInt>10</myInt>" +
   "<key>1</key>" +
  "</Child>");

/* WORKING
StringReader sr = new StringReader(
  "<Child>" +
   "<myInt xmlns=\"http://www.demo.com\">10</myInt>" +
   "<key>1</key>" +
  "</Child>");*/

Child myChild = (Child)mySerializer.Deserialize(sr);
```

On workstation framework the namespace isn't needed.

So i get problems using webservices, since the namespace isn't included in parent fields.

Comment: Are you sure it's version 3.5?  I don't think that version exists.  There was 3/3.1 and 4/4.5.  I've only been working with CF since version 5 back in 2--1, so if it's really a version 3.x, it probably doesn't support modern webservice standards.

Comment: You're not using ColdFusion, so you shouldn't include the coldfusion tag. ColdFusion != Compact Framework. It looks as though this is your second post on this issue (first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402678/webservice-cf-3-5-and-class-inheritance/) and you've tagged it incorrectly both times.

Comment: Please show code. Also, is this a [WebService] with [WebMethod]?

Comment: Is this the same problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402678/webservice-cf-3-5-and-class-inheritance?

Comment: Yes seems to be a serializer problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. Is the web service written in .net or coldfusion? Your question sort of reads like it's coldfusion, but to my knowledge cfc's (classes) didn't exist in cf3.5.

Not too mention you're using an absolutely ancient version of cf. Version 9 has been available for more than a year now.

Answer (score 0):

For derived classes as response in WebServices i have a WorkAround using SoapExtension and Reflection.